# How to check if document exists in collection using mongo Java driver 3.0+

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Using the new [3.0+ java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) from mongo what is the best way to check if a document exists in a collection.

I have looked at [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) and tried to do something similar. I have only gotten as far as this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(eq("code", "abcdefg")).projection(Projections.include("_id")).limit(1);
```

This returns a FindIterable but how do you check it has found anything at all ? If you can please provide a code example.

I did try:

```
if (!iterable.first().isEmpty()){System.out.println(" RESILT IS FOUND ");}else{System.out.println(" RESULT IS NOT FOUND ");}
```

but when the query returns nothing it dies with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oss.niagaramqtt.MongoLib.exists(MongoLib.java:58)
    at com.oss.niagaramqtt.MongoLib.<init>(MongoLib.java:47)
    at com.oss.niagaramqtt.startup.main(startup.java:24)
```

Indeed is this the correct approach overall for checking the existence of a document?

**EDIT:**
This could be the answer please confirm:

```
MongoCursor<Document> iterable = collection.find(eq("code", "abcdefg")).projection(Projections.include("_id")).limit(1).iterator();                
if (iterable.hasNext()){System.out.println(" RESILT IS FOUND ");}else{System.out.println(" RESULT IS NOT FOUND ");}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way is good if you need to load this document in case it exists. If you don't need to load it then you can use MongoCollection.count method like:

```
    long count = collection.count(new BsonDocument("code", new BsonString("abcdefg")));
    if (count > 0){System.out.println(" RESILT IS FOUND ");}else{System.out.println(" RESULT IS NOT FOUND ");}
```

[Update] In case data is stored on a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress. So it's safer to use `aggregate` function instead:

```
    Iterator<Document> it = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$match", new Document("code", "abcdefg")),
            new Document("$group", new Document("_id", null).append("count", 
                    new Document("$sum", 1))))).iterator();
    int count = it.hasNext() ? (Integer)it.next().get("count") : 0;
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/ for more details.

Comment: On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [count operation at java API 3.0](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#count-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.CountOptions-) in a collection.

You can basically do:

```
   MongoClient mongoClient2 = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
   long count =  mongoClient2.getDatabase("mongoBase")               
                             .getCollection("collection")
                             .count(new Document("code", "abcdefg"));
   if(count>0){
   //exists 
   }
```

you will find great examples here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/8866de115d45ea73a39da9360159d3fbb6390dd9/driver/src/examples/tour

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways how to check if document exists in mongodb collection. For example,

1) Using method [count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/):

```
long found = database.getCollection("mainCollection").count(new Document("title", title).append("url", url));

if (found == 0) {
    collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title).append("url", url));
}
```

2) Using [FindIterable](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html):

```
FindIterable<Document> found = database.getCollection("mainCollection").find(new Document("title", title).append("url", url));

if (found.first() == null) {
    collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title).append("url", url));
}
```

3) Using [Document](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html):

```
Document found = database.getCollection("mainCollection").find(new Document("title", title).append("url", url)).first()

if (found == null) {
    collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title).append("url", url));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers already here, I have been doing this in java:

```
if (entryRepository.exists(Example.of(entry))) {
            log.error(String.format("Entry exists already"));
            return true;
}
```