# MongoDB Document exists

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I check if a Document exists in `MongoDB v3` (Java)?

In a "`forEach`" I can't return true, because itself is a void

```
    public static boolean exists(UUID uuid) {
    Main.getMongo().getCollection("players").find(new Document("uuid", uuid.toString())).forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        public void apply(Document document) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT) Related but perhaps not the answer:

See the following, which presents a few alternatives, depending on why you're checking for existence.

[java mongo driver 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508382/java-mongo-driver-3-0/32509268#32509268)

Comment: This is not the answer. Please write the same in comment.